# Deserialization of Java Object ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, serialization

Firstly, I know very little about Java. I'm taking part in a Capture the Flag and need to deserialize some Base64 encoded cookie information to alter some parameter values to progress further with the challenge.

I have reviewed many other questions on SO about this error message, but my limited Java knowledge (having only ever written Java code for the purpose of answering this challenge question) means I need some expertise to help me quickly understand.

I have the following code to decode the base64 cookie value and then attempt to deserialize.

```
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.io.*;

public class decode {
   public static void main(String args[]){

      try {
         // get the encoded string and print for reference
         String base64encodedString = "mybase64encodedstring==";
         System.out.println("Base64 encoded string : " + base64encodedString + "\n");

         // base64 decode and print
         byte[] base64decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64encodedString);
         System.out.println("Base64 decoded string : " + new String(base64decodedBytes, "utf-8") + "\n");

         // deserialize 
         InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(base64decodedBytes);

         ObjectInputStream obin = new ObjectInputStream(in);
         Object object = obin.readObject();
         obin.close();

         System.out.println("Object class is " + object.getClass().toString());

      }catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e){
         System.out.println("UnsupportedEncodingException :" + e.getMessage());
         return;
      }catch(IOException e) {
         System.out.println("IOException :" + e.getMessage());
         return;
      }catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
         System.out.println("Class not found");
         e.printStackTrace();
         return;
      }
   }
}
```

Note, I've not included my actual base64 encoded string in fear of others on the challenge googling for it and finding the answer they may also need :)

The output of the base64 decoded string is something like the following format:

```
Base64 decoded string : ��srcom.myapp.name.model.User��x�g�e�Iidis_adminpasswordtLjava/lang/String;L        password2q~usernameq~xpt<somepasswordstring>
bsmith
```

And the error I get is:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.myapp.name.model.User
```

I understand that this relates to something about com.myapp.name.model.User not being in a ClassPath? I've no idea what that means and what I need to do in order to deserialize this data.

Any help on this appreciated!

Comment: '`com.myapp.name.model.User` not being in a ClassPath' is exactly what it means. That class has to be available to your JVM when executing, just as the class you posted does, and via the same mechanism.

Comment: Maybe by changing `System.out.println("Object class is " + object.getClass().toString());` to `System.out.println("Object class is " + ((User) object).toString());` can help?

Comment: Thanks @EJP how can I make it available. A new .java file with a com.myapp... class declared?

Comment: @MincongHuang I get unknown symbol User

Comment: You need to declare the import at the head of the file using `import com.myapp.name.model.User;`. And you need to make sure the class `User` is in the classpath. By the way, where is your `com.myapp.name.model.User`?

Comment: @MincongHuang He doesn't need that import with this code. He is getting an exception at runtime, not a compilation error..

Comment: @m0atz The class being deserialized is part of the specification of the problem. If it isn't there, you can't solve it.

Comment: ok, interesting. thanks for the pointers guys.